# How to use character variables in @formula macro?

Tags: julia

How can I use variables in `@fomula()`?

I'd like to write something like

```
var1 = "price + volume"
ModelFormula = @formula(dep_var ~ 0 + $var1)
```

Which would be interpreted as

```
@formula(dep_var ~ 0 + price + volume)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation about [programmatic model construction](https://juliastats.org/StatsModels.jl/stable/formula/#Constructing-a-formula-programmatically) in StatsModels.jl (which you presumably use).  In your case, it seems something like the following would be sufficient:

```
Term(:dep_var) ~ ConstantTerm(0) + Term(:price) + Term(:volume)
```

Or `fold(+, Term.([:price, :volume]))` if the names are given as an array.

Comment: Great, thanks. Can I use `zerocorr()` in such construction?

Comment: I have no idea what that is, but you might be able to find something useful in the [section about syntax extension](https://juliastats.org/StatsModels.jl/stable/internals/#extend-runtime).

Answer (score 0):

...spent some time on this one. Please post answers if there are better ways.

Works this way:

```
var1 = "price + volume"

ModelFormula = @eval @formula(dep_var ~ 0 + $(Symbol(var1)))
```

Although, passing the whole expression `"dep_var = 0 + price + volume"` generates an error:

```
julia> formula = "a ~ 0 + b"
julia> @eval @formula($(Symbol(formula)))
ERROR: LoadError: type Symbol has no field head
```

edit2:
digging deeper, it seems that with this approach you have you pass each variable on it's own, so that `@formula` interprets each independently..

```
var1 = "price"
var2 = "volume"

ModelFormula = @eval @formula(dep_var ~ 0 + $(Symbol(var1)) + $(Symbol(var2)))
```